# Protractor: How to access sibling element?

Tags: protractor

[Source Elements Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd4zT.png)

How can I click the `div input checkbox` using the `span data-original-title` without using xpath?

With the help of @eLRuLL :

```
var keynoteCheckbox = $('[data-original-title="Keynote"]')
  .element(by.xpath('../../preceding-sibling::div'))
  .$('#Checkbox2');
browser.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", keynoteCheckbox);
```

*Had to use `executeScript` as there was another element sitting on top of it*

Comment: which div? the one below `li`? or the one with `id=filter-spinner...`

Comment: Below. Essentially the `input` tag

Comment: Why cant you use `element(by.id('Checkbox2')).click()`?

Comment: Because then I won't be able to specify the checkbox I want to click. I want to specify it by the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `div` element is not sibling of that `span`, but of the `label` parent, try with:

```
by.xpath('../../preceding-sibling::div')
```

Comment: `$('[data-original-title="Keynote"]').element(by.xpath('../../preceding-sibling::div/input')).$('#Checkbox2')`

Failed: No element found using locator: By(css, #Checkbox2)

Comment: sorry I missed you are getting it already with `Checkbox2`, please check again

Comment: Excellent that worked but I had to use this function to get it to click properly: `element.getWebElement().then(function(elm) {
    browser.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", elm);
  });`


Is there any possible way to do this exact thing but without using xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath selectors is not a better choice as it slows down the element finding mechanism.

I have designed a plugin to address this specific issues: [protractor-css-booster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster)

The plugin provides some handly locators to find out siblings in a better way and most importantly with CSS selector.

using this plugin, you can directly use:

```js
var elem = element(by.cssContainingText('div.text-label','SomeText')).element(by.followingSibling('div'));
```

You can always checkout the other handy methods available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster)...

Hope, it will help you...